# show the information of a table in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to show the information of state from a table in sql into combobox1 and based of what we chosed in combobox1 I wanna to show the cities that is in the state.
wpf and entity framework
need some help
table state:
id int,
name nvarchar(50)

table city:
id int,
name nvarchar(50),
stateId int

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create `List<State> StateList` which contain all state object,
give

### XAML

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource = {Binding StateList} SelectedItem = {Binding State} 
DisplayMamberPath = "Name"/>`
```

### C#

```
List<State> StateList // All State
```